# Penultimate match making cases

Tags: list, scala, recursion, pattern-matching

```
def penultimate(l:List[Int]):Int = l match{
    case x::y::Nil => x
    case x::tail => penultimate(tail)
    case _ => ???
}
```

The penultimate is the element that precedes the last element in a list.

In the first case, we have a list of 2 elements. Which is the base case?

The second case, we will call recursively the same method on the tail of the list. And the number of elements in the list will decrease per one for every recursive call.

What exactly is the last case? When will the 3rd case ever occur?

Comment: Yes, it is the empty list, you can only throw exception then.

Comment: What is the penultimate of an empty list or s list with just one element? Exactly there isn't, so you either throw an exception or instead of retuning **Int** you can return an **Option[Int]**.

Comment: So it's better practice to replace     case _ => ??? by case _ => Option[Int] ?

Comment: @user90379 it depends on what you consider a best practice but in Functional Programming yes, the idea is not to throw exceptions. So the final code would be like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/I4kqZW2eQC2SLWHNxAosfQ)

Answer (score 1):

The last case will occur if the initial list has fewer than 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

So, like you explained yourself, if there are two elements in the list, the first case matches.

Otherwise, if there are one or more, it is the second case?

What's left? Last case matches empty lists. If there is no first element to chop off, it will fall through the second case, and hit the last one. You can leave `???` there or throw some other exception if you prefer. Or just do `l.head` (it'll throw for you).

I figure, you are just writing this function for exercise, but just thought I'd mention it anyway: what you are doing is equivalent to `l.init.last`